# Create a MultiDimensional Array with PHP and Mysql Foreach Loops

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am needing to create a multidimensional array with sql and loops. However only one result gets set into the array, the last result is overwriting the previous results. Here is what the array structure looks like:

```
 ->value = Array (4)
   CartID => "1299"
   Date => "2012-09-27 09:17:20"
   Amount => "85.00"
         0 => Array (8)
         CartStatus => "Purchased"
         Date => "2012-09-27 09:17:20"
         CartID => "1299"
         Sequence => "1"
         Amount => "-85.00"
         Comments => " , Refund Status: "
```

Here is my code:

```
    $txarray = array();
    foreach ($data as $transaction) {
    $CartVar = $transaction['CartID'];
    $CartStatus = $transaction['Status'];
    $CartDate = $transaction['DateTime'];
    $CartTotal = $transaction['Total'];
    $txarray = array('CartID' => $CartVar, 'Date' => $CartDate, 'Amount' => $CartTotal);
        $sql1 = $db->query("SQL stuff");
        foreach ($sql1 as $refund) {
        $CartID = $refund['CartID'];
        $Sequence = $refund['Sequence'];
        $TrxType = $refund['TrxType'];
        $ParentID = $refund['ParentID'];
        $TotalSum = '-'.$refund['Amount'];
        $Comments = ' '.$refund['Comments'];
        $Comments .= ', Refund Status: '.ucwords($refund['Status']);
        $txarray[] = array('CartStatus' => $CartStatus, 'Date' => $CartDate, 'CartID' => $CartID, 'Sequence' => $Sequence, 'TrxType' => $TrxType, 'ParentID' => $ParentID, 'Amount' => $TotalSum, 'Comments' => $Comments);
    }
```

Comment: This is a classic example of people abusing associative arrays when you could create an object. As your code base gets larger doing stuff like this will only become more and more painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at above code snippet $txarray variable is overwritten due to code.

```
$txarray = array('CartID' => $CartVar, 'Date' => $CartDate, 'Amount' => $CartTotal);
```

It needs to be replaced it with

```
$txarray[] = array('CartID' => $CartVar, 'Date' => $CartDate, 'Amount' => $CartTotal);
```

or alternatively you can use array_push() function which will push arrays thereby resulting into multidimensional array.
e.g.

```
 array_push($txarray,array('CartID' => $CartVar, 'Date' => $CartDate, 'Amount' =>      $CartTotal));
```

For more documentation about array_push function please refer the documentation in below mentioned url.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$txarray = array('CartID' => $CartVar, 'Date' => $CartDate, 'Amount' => $CartTotal);
```

destroys any previous array'd you'd created in earlier iterations.

Comment: User doesnt want the last result to overwrite the previous results which means he needs the data received from earlier iterations.